# Jtable renderer color avoid invert of colors

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering

I have made a jtable which contains data

"Marc", "Caissier", "0" 
"Julien", "Caissier", "1" 
"Jason", "Danceur", "2"
"Marie", "Danceur", "3" 
"John", "Vendeur", "4"

In order to see all jobs easily, i would like to paint one color by job. alternativly

Example : 
Row 0 : color grey (because the job is Caissier)
Row 1 : color grey (because the job is Caissier)
Row 2 : color pink (because the job has changed for Danceur)
Row 3 : color pink (because the job is again Danceur)
Row 4 : color grey (because the job is Vendeur...)

It seems to works, but i don't know why, when i click on a row, the renderer is called again and the color change and then it doesn't work.

So, i have decided to call jtable.repaint each time the user click on a row.
But i do that, there is a bad event.
All row which was pink become grey and All row which was grey become pink.
I paste a snippet of my code.
You see the bug if you launch JtableColor.java and then clik on id 4 for example, then click on id 2.

[image]

[image]

I have put breakpoint and trying to resolve my problem. I haven't found a solution.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;



public class JtableColor {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Object rowData[][] = {
        { "Marc", "Caissier", "0" },
        { "Julien", "Caissier", "1" },
        { "Jason", "Danceur", "2" },
        { "Marie", "Danceur", "3" },
        { "John", "Vendeur", "4" } ,
    };

    Object columnNames[] = { "Prenom", "Job", "Id" };
    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    rendererColor jtca1 = new rendererColor();
    for (int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++){
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(jtca1);
    }

    table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            JTable table = (JTable) evt.getSource();
            table.repaint();
        }
    });



    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}

class rendererColor extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private String valueToString = "";
int colAScruter=-1;
int couleur =0;
Color couleurAMettre =Color.GREEN;
Hashtable hash= new Hashtable();

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus,
        int row,
        int columnt) {

    Component c =
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                    isSelected, hasFocus,
                    row, columnt);


    //Association d'une couleur à la table
    int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    String jobBefore = (String) hash.get("jobBefore");

    Vector listeCouleur = new Vector();
    listeCouleur.add(0,Color.PINK);
    listeCouleur.add(1,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    couleur = (Integer) hash.get("couleur");
    boolean change= true;

    String job= (String) table.getValueAt(row,1);

    if (jobBefore.equals("")){
        setBackground((Color)listeCouleur.get(couleur));

    }
    else if (job.equals(jobBefore)){
        setBackground((Color)listeCouleur.get(couleur));
    }
    else{
        if (couleur == 0) couleur=1;
        else if (couleur == 1) couleur=0;
        setBackground((Color)listeCouleur.get(couleur));

    }
    hash.put("jobBefore",job);
    hash.put("couleur",couleur);



    return c;
}


public rendererColor() {
    super();
    hash.put("jobBefore", "");
    hash.put("couleur",0);

}




}
```

Comment: `In order to see all jobs easily, i would like to paint one color by job` Then why not color based upon the value in that column? Right now it seems your rendering is dependent upon prior rendering, not the actual values

Comment: here I have a few questions about

Answer (score 1):

> In order to see all jobs easily, i would like to paint one color by job.
>
> Example : Row 0 : color grey (because the job is Caissier) Row 1 : color grey (because the job is Caissier) Row 2 : color pink (because the job has changed for Danceur) Row 3 : color pink (because the job is again Danceur) Row 4 : color grey (because the job is Vendeur...)

Consider coloring by cell value (your code right now seems to be dependent upon prior rendering eg `jobBefore`). For example, to color all rows pink that have the `Job` value as "Danceur":

```
String job = (String)table.getValueAt(row,1);
if ( job.equals("Danceur") ){
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
}else{
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}
```

This does not take into consideration selections - if you wish to customize the Color for selections, you can do so by checking the isSelected value. Alternatively just use the UI default color

```
if ( isSelected ){
    setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
}
```

There should not be a need to repaint with a `MouseListener` unless you truly need to repaint due to change in logic for the coloring upon the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: I cannot coloring by cell value because, i don't know all jobs. In the future, user can add new user with new job. I don't would like to hard code the color based on value. The option isSelected doens't work.

Comment: How does that prevent you from coloring by cell value? And no hard coding is necessary...use a map, keyed with that cell and valued by a color.  When rendering check if that map key exists, if it does use the color value. If not, generate a color and set the map key/value

Comment: I cannot put colors in a map. In the future i will add a search engine. If a user is looking for job Caissier and Vendeur, all the rows will be in pink or all in grey....